# Python multiprocessing pool number of jobs not correct

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pool

I wrote a python program to launch parallel processes (16) using pool, to process some files. At the beginning of the run, the number of processes is maintained at 16 until almost all files get processed. Then, for some reasons which I don't understand, when there're only a few files left, only one process runs at a time which makes processing time much longer than necessary. Could you help with this?

Comment: Without any code and without any information about your scheduling strategy it will a quite hard to help you. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Probably each process have a dedicated load at start. he stop when finished.

Comment: Hi, the code proceeds in a very straightforward way:   pool multiprocessing.Pool(processes=16), then pool.map(...) is used to map a function to a list of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Force `map()` to use a chunksize of 1 instead of guessing the best value by itself, es.:

```
pool = Pool(16)
pool.map(func, iterable, 1)
```

This should (in theory) guarantee the best distribution of load among workers until the end of the input data.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map)

Answer (score 0):

Python, before starts the execution of the process that you specify in applyasync/asyncmap of Pool, assigns to each worker a piece of the work.

For example, lets say that you have 8 files to process and you start a Pool with 4 workers.

Before starting the file processing, two specific files will be assigned to each worker. This means that if some worker ends its job earlier than the others, will simply "have a break" and will not start helping the others.

Comment: So, what can I do to make sure that a maximum number of processes (<= 16) always run? Because when there're only several files left only one jobs runs at a time, one after the other, which makes the total time exceedingly long. Thanks!

Comment: Always a maximum number of process run. But for more information I would have to ask for a code example. I cannot answer more without be on specific code.

Comment: Hi, as I wrote in reply to hagello the code proceeds in a very straightforward way: pool multiprocessing.Pool(processes=16), then pool.map(...) is used to map a function to a list of arguments which is the list of files to be processed. Thanks!